Deploying Selenium scraper bot?
I wrote a Selenium script that logs in to a platform for booking interviews automatically, but i never really deployed anything before (I do scraping generally for data collection).
Any ideas on free/cheap options to deploy it?
Note: i would appreciate any mentions to content/courses about the deployment of code in general, am a Data Scientist so all my focus was the last 3 years about the theory but i never really deployed any model/code i made, i just run it locally/collab lol, so if there's some type of content that talks about this subject i would love to read it.
